Why is my grease pencil drawing see-through even though is ON TOP of another grease pencil object?
I'm working on this project and one of my drawings is see-through for some reason, even though it's own grease pencil object AND is in front of the other drawing plane, I have done this project multiple times and this is the first time this happens to me. I already tried activating the "z" pass and changing the stroke placement from "2D world" to "3D world" but it does nothing. This is an example:


And this is what I want, see how the arm is not see through?

Here is the .blend file:

This looks like a unique problem from what you have shown in your question so, I suggest including a sample blend file to reproduce this error. You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share your blend file. Honestly, GP works fine on my end. I too am using Blender 4.1.1 and have not encountered this problem. In fact, I don't need to turn on z-pass, or 3d location for stroke depth order to create overlap.
